# Is there any plug-in to run multiple jobs in Jenkins simultanously for different projects?

Tags: android, ios, jenkins

I have made setup of Jenkins in my system. I am not able to execute 2 or more job at same time.

It is running one after another. Is there any way to run multiple jobs at the same time in different projects.

i.e Consider I have 2 projects Android & iOS. Once I start a job from Android it will take 10 mins. While the android job is running, I am not able to execute job from iOS. It is waiting for Android to complete.

Comment: one plugin you can run one projetct in multiple device in Xcode,  see https://github.com/kitschpatrol/KPRunEverywhereXcodePlugin

Comment: can you specify how *exactly* those 2 jobs are configured? Which plugins have you used? A screenshot would be great. If you do that - it'd be possible for someone to suggest how to tweak the settings without installing additional plugins.

Comment: @KiritModi, Thanks for info. But it was not my question.

Comment: @JanLutenko, I can't share a screenshot. It just 2 different projects. Which should able to run a job at same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a plugin to execute jobs simultaneously as long as the jobs themselves are independent.

What you do need to do is make sure you have multiple executors that can take jobs from the queue.

If you click on a node in the build executor panel then hit 'configure', you can set the number of executors to be more than one.  By default jenkins has only one Build executor, 'Master'.

Be careful doing this if your jobs rely on one another or share resources.  If that is the case, then you are better served by using a [slave](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) executor.